# regex with space and letters only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a regular expression that only accepts letters. I'm not really good in regex, thats why I don't know how to include spaces in my regex.

**My HTML:**

```
<input id="input" />
```

**My js / jQuery code:**

```
$('#input').on('keyup', function() {
      var RegExpression = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/; 

      if (RegExpression.test($('#input').val())) {

      } 
      else {
          $('#input').val("");
      }
});​
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

use this expression

```
var RegExpression = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/;
```

***Update: 27-April-2023***

```js
function validate(){
  const regEx1 = /[^a-zA-Z\s]+/;
    input.value = input.value.replace(regEx1, '');
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" onkeyup="return validate();">
```

Comment: any reason to include the space as well as all whitespace in the character class?

Comment: guys im having a });â€‹ error on the last part of the code whats wrong with it? i suppose my codes are correct $('.letters-only').on('keyup',function() {
    var RegExpression = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/; 

    if (RegExpression.test($(this).val())) {
    } 
    else {
        $('this').val("");
    }
});​

Comment: first change code in else condition `$(this).val("");` and then check

Comment: @JohnDvorak One reason could be 'cause some people names are built by two different ones (eg. Anna Maria, Lola May, etc.)

Answer (score 10):

```
$('#input').on('keyup', function() {
     var RegExpression = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/;  
     ...

});
```

`\s` will allow the space

Comment: \s is any whitespace, not just `0x20`

Comment: Yep, this is not only the space, but I'm expecting he will filter the input value also on server-side

Answer (score 4):

Try this demo please: http://jsfiddle.net/sgpw2/

Thanks Jan for spaces `\s` rest there is some good detail in this link:

http://www.jquery4u.com/syntax/jquery-basic-regex-selector-examples/#.UHKS5UIihlI

Hope it fits your need `:)`

**code**

```
 $(function() {

    $("#field").bind("keyup", function(event) {
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
        if (regex.test($("#field").val())) {
            $('.validation').html('valid');
        } else {
            $('.validation').html("FAIL regex");
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: The second link is decent, but neither the fiddle nor the code targets the question, "how to include spaces".

Comment: @JanDvorak ah bruv `\s` will take care of space I hav rectified man, thanks for the comment lol did you dw-ed me can you remove it now plz :) **working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/sgpw2/

Answer (score 1):

this one works great for me

```
/[^a-zA-Z' ']/g
```

Answer (score 0):

regex expression:

```
var reg_name_lastname = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/;
```

Validation to the user_name input field

```
if(!reg_name_lastname.test($('#user_name').val())){ //
    alert("Correct your First Name: only letters and spaces.");
    valid = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Allowed only characters & spaces. Ex : `Jayant Lonari`

```
if (!/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/.test(NAME)) {
    //Throw Error
}
```