# I have this form, and I cant get it it to get validated

Tags: javascript, html

I have this form and it needs to be validated. For example, no numbers in the name field, and Message part can't be more than 200 characters. I have tried writing JavaScript code but it doesn't just work.

```
<aside id="sidebar">
  <div class="dark">
    <form id="quote" >
      <h3>Get A Quote</h3>

      <div>
        <label>Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Email</label><br>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Message</label><br>
        <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="button_1" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</aside>
```

I expect for it also to say if a part is not filled but I can't get it to work.

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for this -> [Form data validation | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation)

Comment: You need to provide an [mcve] or we can't tell you what is wrong with your JS

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: "no numbers in the name field, and Message part cant be more than 200 charachters" — Try not to ask multiple questions at once.

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/) … and it isn't useful for it to *duplicate* a label either.

Comment: Have any of the below answers resolved your question? If so, please choose a correct answer *(and upvote any others you deem helpful)* to close the question. Else, please post comments below the answer(s) to advise how we can assist further. *So far, all answers have been downvoted, so your input would be appreciated.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate which name accepts only text and spaces you can use this expression /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/ read about it in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12778207/615274. Validating the message is a little simpler. It is possible to define the maximum number of characters to accept in textarea using [maxlength attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea). This possibility can prevent you from writing code. Please look at the following example

```js
const form = document.forms.form;

form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit, true);

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const name = this.name.value;
    const message = this.message.value;

    if (!isValidName(name)) {
        alert('Not valid name!');

        return false;
    }

    if (!isValidMessage(message)) {
        alert('Not valid message!');

        return false;
    }

    this.submit();
}

function isValidName(name) {
    // const expresion = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    const expresion = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;

    return expresion.test(name);
}

function isValidMessage(message) {
    if (message.length > 200) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" name="form">
    <h3>Get A Quote</h3>

    <div>
        <label>Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Email</label><br>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Message</label><br>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" minlength="1" maxlength="200" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button class="button_1" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `pattern` attribute for this and on js side use `checkValidity()` to check if the input is valid or not.

```js
$('#name').on('keyup', (ev) => {
  var isValid = $('#name')[0].checkValidity();
 $('span').html(isValid ? 'yes': 'no');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]*">
<div>isValid: <span></span></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The link provided by Andreas is definitely your friend for this issue. 
For your specific needs, you want "required", maxlength="200", and (I think) "pattern='^\D+$'".

Comment: I'm hoping my downvoter would be willing to say whether the problem with this answer was that I provided too much 'free code' and not enough education in response to a weak question?